# Meaning of time derivative of the Lorentz factor $\gamma$?

Tags: special-relativity, kinematics, differentiation, lorentz-symmetry

This question about the Lorentz factor $\gamma$ in special relativity. I know what $\gamma$ means and how to drive. I'm wondering if I have time derivative of $\gamma$, what dose it mean conceptually?

Answer (score 6):

For a test particle, it's essentially the power being delivered to a test particle by a force, because $E=m\gamma$ (or $E=m\gamma c^2$ in units where $c\ne1$).

Comment: One typically sets $c=1$ to save time, but here it seems it had the opposite effect :-) If you had written $E=\gamma mc^2$ from the beginning, you could have avoided the parenthetical clarification altogether. Anyway, I guess the more precise statement that $\dot\gamma$ is the power per unit rest-energy, right? Does that make it more transparent? Also, IIRC, it is the zero component of the four-force, right?